# echo time doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

I want to echo the time of the server, or the time in Europe/London or Europe/Lisbon.
This is my code but for some reason it's displaying the time on the system or something. I mean, in my PC I see the correct time but in a tablet which is an hour late it shows the time of the tablet o.O
here's the code:

```
        <?php 
    $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon') );
    $today = getdate($date); ?>
    <script>
        var d = new Date(Date.UTC(<?php /*echo $today['year'].",".$today['mon'].",".$today['mday'].",".$today['hours'].",".$today['minutes'].",".$today['seconds'];*/ echo $date->format('Y,m,d,H,i,s'); ?>));
        setInterval(function() {
            d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 1);
            $('#timer').text((d.getHours() +':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() ));
        }, 1000);
    </script> 
    <p><div id="timer"></div></p>
```

Comment: JavaScript is client side, so naturally it would print out the client side date information, while PHP is server side and naturally would print the server side date. Are you using the same host to test with the PC and tablet?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois you should make that an answer :) however, it does not account for timezone

Comment: yeah.. the website is hosted already.. I'm building it "live online" xD

Comment: @Hallur That's what OP wants, no? Display the server time.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois That is how I understand it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do it using JavaScript

**Example:**

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var H = date.getHours();
  var M = date.getMinutes();
  var S = date.getSeconds(); 
  $('#timer').text(H+':'+M+':'+S);
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: nowhere in this code, does it account for the time zone.

Comment: **This is not the solution to the problem**. The problem is that when time of computer or any device changes, **the time on web page also changes**. The user wants to get the time from the server. The time you are displaying will also change with my system clock! So this is something which he was already getting!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon');
  $today = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>

  <div id="timer"></div>

  <script>
     var d = new Date('<?php echo $today ?>');      
     setInterval(function() {
         d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 1);
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML=(d.getHours() +':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds() );
     }, 1000);     
   </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Will you please explain why you think this is the correct answer?